# Performant way to convert adjacency list to links for undirected graph

Tags: javascript, data-structures, graph

I have an adjacency list like below:

```
const list = [
 [1, 6, 8],
 [0, 4, 6, 9],
 [4, 6],
 [4, 5, 8],
 // ...
];
```

I need to create a set of links for an undirected graph without duplicates (example bellow).
Such links as `[0,1]` and `[1,0]` are considered duplicates.

```
const links = [
 [ 0, 1 ], // duplicates
 [ 0, 6 ],
 [ 0, 8 ],
 [ 1, 0 ], // duplicates
 [ 1, 4 ],
 // ...
]
```

Right now I do it this way:

```
const links = new Set;
const skip = [];

list.forEach( (v, i) => {
    v.forEach( j => {
        if (skip.indexOf(j) === -1) {
            links.add([i, j]);
        }
    })
    skip.push(i);
})
```

I am wondering if there is a better pattern to solve this kind of task on massive arrays.

Answer (score 2):

You could sort your link tuple values, skip the check `skip.indexOf(j)` and let `Set` take care of the duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a stringed array as value for the for the set, because an array with only sorted value is checking with strict mode in the set.

A primitive data type, like string works best.

```js
var list = [[1, 6, 8], [0, 4, 6, 9], [4, 6], [4, 5, 8]],
    links = new Set;

list.forEach((v, i) => v.forEach(j => links.add([Math.min(i, j), Math.max(i, j)].join())));
   
console.log([...links]);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use one object to store `value: index` that has already been used and then check that object before adding to array.

```js
const list = [[1, 6, 8],[0, 4, 6, 9],[4, 6],[4, 5, 8],];
var o = {},r = []

list.forEach(function(e, i) {
  e.forEach(function(a) {
    if (o[i] != a) {
      r.push([i, a])
      o[a] = i
    }
  })
})

console.log(JSON.stringify(r))
```

With ES6 arrow functions you can write the same like this.

```js
const list = [[1, 6, 8], [0, 4, 6, 9], [4, 6], [4, 5, 8],];
var o = {}, r = []

list.forEach((e, i) => e.forEach(a => o[i] != a ? (r.push([i, a]), o[a] = i) : null))
console.log(JSON.stringify(r))
```